# How to select first character of <i> which is inside a <p> tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying something like below,

```
p+i:first-letter
{
background-color:red;
}
```

or

```
p i:first-letter
{
background-color:red;
}
```

on html snippet like this

```
<p>
<i>  Sample text</i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-letter` does not work on inline elements such as a `i`. `:first-letter` works on block elements such as a paragraph, table caption, table cell, list item, or those with the `inline-block` property applied.

```
<div>
    <p>
       <i>Sample text</i>
    </p>
</div>
```

css

```
i { display: inline-block; }

div p:last-child i:first-child:first-letter { font-weight: bold }
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xN3Z3/)

Comment: I tried like this. 

p:first-letter i
    {
    background-color:red;
    } this is not working as well. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: @Prince Ashitaka: This solution is needlessly complicated. All you need to do is make `i` an inline block; everything else in this answer is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

A first line has only meaning in a block-container box, therefore the ::first-letter pseudo-element has only an effect on elements with a display value of block, inline-block, table-cell, list-item or table-caption. In all other cases, ::first-letter has no effect.

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::first-letter